# Stop multiple keyboard entries in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have some python code that uses a pygame window to establish which key is being pressed.  When a key is pressed, the code heads off and does things before coming back to see what the next key pressed might be.

The problem I have is that if the user presses a key repeatedly, even while the 'code heads off and does things', pygame seems to remember what has been pressed rather than waiting for the next keypress.  What I want is for the code to ignore any keypresses while the 'go and do stuff' is done then once that's finished, get the next keypress.  Hope this makes sense!

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((450,282))
screen.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

def go_and_do_things():
    print("doing things")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("things done")

# Loop as long as done == False
while not done:    
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            keypressedcode = event.key # This is the ASCII code
            print("keypressedcode is " + str(keypressedcode))
            go_and_do_things()


        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    clock.tick(60)

time.sleep(4)
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pygame.event.clear](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.clear). As written below, it will discard any keypresses during go_and_do_things().

```
while not done:    
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something

         # Any key down
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            keypressedcode = event.key # This is the ASCII code
            print("keypressedcode is " + str(keypressedcode))

            go_and_do_things()
            pygame.event.clear(eventtype=[pygame.KEYDOWN,
                                          pygame.KEYUP)


        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is a fairly simple problem, you just need to add another
>   event.type for keyup. You also need to add a variable to make it stop
>   running which I will label as stopV `if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
>        stopV = True` This should let you instantly stop it when you want to. edit because I want to reword this:

Re-doing this to make it more clear.

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((450,282))
screen.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
unClick = False
```

```
def go_and_do_things():
     if unClick == False
         print("hello")
         # do anything you want in the function here
     else
         return
```

```
while not done:    
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something

         # Any key down
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            keypressedcode = event.key # This is the ASCII code

            print("keypressedcode is " + str(keypressedcode))

            go_and_do_things()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

            unClick == True
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand the concept of keyup but nor too sure where it needs to go and what stopV will do.  Could you please elaborate many thanks

Comment: @user1829877 I redid and edited my entire answer with some variables. I replaced stopV with unClick. This is much more detailed and if this helps you please approve it.